# Why is it recommended to keep the WH suspension period to 15 mins when the result cache will be used for the next 24 hours across users/roles/WHs?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I read from one of the Udemy courses that it's recommended to keep the WH suspension time to 15 mins to get the most out of the result cache. I understand that the clock will be reset to 24 hours up to 30 days every time the same query is being executed. What I don't understand is how the WH suspension time of WH is related to the benefit of cache.

Can somebody please explain If I'm misunderstanding this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

While a warehouse is running, even if you are not using it, you are being charged for it.
When a warehouse is suspended its cache is dropped.
So what you set the suspension time to should be based on a cost-benefit analysis: the cost of keeping the warehouse running if no-one is using it versus the benefit of having the cache available if the warehouse is used

Comment: Thanks for the response Nick! But, I tried running a query once and then run it again after the WH went to suspension state to check If the cache is getting re-used. It did. Actually, The WH didn't even come back to live which means that the result cache is still available even after the WH suspended

Comment: Hi Nick, After few more kinds of research I just came to know that only the WH cache (Also known as Local disk cache) will vanish once the WH is suspended and it's applicable for the result cache. Result cache will be available for 24 hours since when it last run up to 30 days irrespective of the WH is alive or suspended.

Comment: Please feel free to disagree with my point. We will discuss more If required

Comment: I was talking about the warehouse cache, not the results cache: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-considerations.html#how-does-warehouse-caching-impact-queries

Answer (score 0):

As you said the result cache stands for 24h.

It will be reused if all the prerequisite [listed in documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-persisted-results.html#retrieval-optimization) are met.
If your query doesn't allow you to use the cache result then Snowflake will try to use cache in underlying layers.

Warehouse cache (or Local disk cache) allow you to optimize queries which can not use result cache (documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-persisted-results.html#retrieval-optimization)).
Le Local Disk Cache will only be available as long as your warehouse is not suspended. If Result cache and Local Disk Cache are not available, Snowflake will use Remote Disk cache which is the more expensive in terms of performance.
For benchmark purpose you can force Snowflake to bypass result cache using

```
SET USE_CACHED_RESULT = false
```

Good overview of caching concept in Snowflake can be found here :
[Caching-in-Snowflake-Data-Warehouse](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Caching-in-Snowflake-Data-Warehouse)